# Xamarin Forms - Best Method for Connecting to Wordpress through API

Tags: c#, wordpress, xaml, xamarin.forms, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to connect to my Wordpress website using a REST API through my iOS app written in Xamarin Forms.

My workflow is this:

1. User enters in their username and password in the login screen on the app.
2. The code will connect to my wordpress website to see if the username / password matches the one in wordpress.
3. If it matches, then proceed to the next page which lists the user's details.

Here's my code:
XAML

```
<Label x:Name="Login" Text="Login" TextColor="Black"></Label>

<Entry x:Name="LoginUsername" Placeholder="Username *" PlaceholderColor="Gray" />

<Entry x:Name="LoginPassword" Placeholder="Password *" PlaceholderColor="Gray" IsPassword="True" />

<Button x:Name="LoginButton" Text="Login" BackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White" Clicked="BtnLoginHandler"></Button>
```

CS

```
public async Task<Customers> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            string GetAllCustomersApiUrl = string.Format("{0}/wc-api/v3/customers/4/?consumer_key={1}&consumer_secret={2}", website_url, consumer_key, consumer_secret);
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetAllCustomersApiUrl);
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return customers;
        }
```

I think i'm missing something during the authentication etc for it doesn't work.

I've looked around online but there's a few solutions that have been deprecated.

What's the best method to retrieve user data from Wordpress successfully?

Any guidance / documentation / code would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Sign-in is very security critical process. If the end-user's ID/Password managed by other business such like Google, Facebook and so on, they don't allow you to sign-in the end-user without reliable internet browser. Take a look about OAuth.

Comment: Do you get the json from the website and the json include the username / password?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Does it crash or give you an exception or error?  Do you get an HTTP response code?  If the problem is in the auth step, why didn't you include that code in your post?

Comment: Thanks @donggas90 I'll have a look at OAuth

Comment: Thanks @WendyZang-MSFT yes I can get the json from the website and it has the username but the password is in WRITE only mode so I can't retrieve it so it's difficult for me to compare if the username / password is validated before proceeding

Comment: Hi @Jason I was trying to be descriptive as possible by including everything. I'll include the error messages next time.

Comment: Have you try to set the same type for password with username when you get from the json data?

Comment: Thanks @WendyZang-MSFT I think the password field is set to WRITE-ONLY for security purposes. It would be good to just get a response code to validate the username and password and my app can take care of the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Need to use JWT Auth plugin to help authenticate the username and password.